# while loop returns only last values from query table in java when generating xml

Tags: java, sql-server, xml, loops, while-loop

I try to get xml from sql query, but in xml i get only last values of query. i understand that i have mistake in loop, but can not determine it

My Code:

```
while (MetaAlgQwery.next()) {
                ArrayOfCubeSeria aofCubeSeria = new ArrayOfCubeSeria();
                List<CubeSeria> cubeSeriaList = new ArrayList<CubeSeria>();
                aofCubeSeria.setCubeSeria(cubeSeriaList);
                cubeDataSet.setSeries(aofCubeSeria);
                cubeSeriaList.add(cubeSeria);
                cubeDataSetlist.add(cubeDataSet);

                ArrayOfCubeDimension aofCubeDimensionSP = new ArrayOfCubeDimension();
                cubeSeriaItem.setDimensions(aofCubeDimensionSP);

                List<CubeDimension> dimensionList = new ArrayList<CubeDimension>();

                for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {

                    String Cod = metaData.getColumnName(i);
                    String Value = MetaAlgQwery.getString(Cod); 

                    if (!Cod.equals("value")) {
                        CubeDimension cubeDimension = new CubeDimension();
                        cubeDimension.setCod(Cod);
                        cubeDimension.setValue(Value);
                        dimensionList.add(cubeDimension);
                    }

                    aofCubeDimensionSP.setCubeDimension(dimensionList);
                }

                cubeSeriaItem.setValue(MetaAlgQwery.getString("value"));
            }
```

xml that i get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CubeResponse>
<Cube>
    <Concept>U6000427</Concept>
    <DataSets>
        <CubeDataSet>
            <dt_end>2017-11-30T00:00:00+06:00</dt_end>
            <Series>
                <CubeSeria>
                    <Dimensions/>
                    <Items>
                        <CubeSeriaItem>
<Dimensions>
    <CubeDimension>
        <Cod>SP</Cod>           <------------
        <value>1</value>        <------------
    </CubeDimension>
    <CubeDimension>
        <Cod>KATO</Cod>              <------------
        <value>155200000</value>      <------------
    </CubeDimension>
</Dimensions>
<value>1</value>
                        </CubeSeriaItem>
                    </Items>
                </CubeSeria>
            </Series>
        </CubeDataSet>
        <CubeDataSet>
            <dt_end>2017-11-30T00:00:00+06:00</dt_end>
            <Series>
                <CubeSeria>
                    <Dimensions/>
                    <Items>
                        <CubeSeriaItem>
<Dimensions>
    <CubeDimension>
        <Cod>SP</Cod>       <-----------repeating 
        <value>1</value>    <------------
    </CubeDimension>
    <CubeDimension>
        <Cod>KATO</Cod>     <----------------
        <value>155200000</value> <-----------repeating with prev array
    </CubeDimension>
</Dimensions>
<value>1</value>
                        </CubeSeriaItem>
                    </Items>
                </CubeSeria>
            </Series>
        </CubeDataSet>
```

i want to have different SP and KATO from query, but result gives me only the last ones. my query returns this

**SP** **KATO**

1      154600000
2      151000000
1      315043000
1      155200000

Comment: Sorry, this might be clear for you, but I've got no idea what you are doing here...

Comment: thanks. i've solved that problem